# Why some sites are blocked by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

*Google Chrome* browser doesn't show many sites, instead it displays the message, for instance, the image below referring to URL [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/) (and this issue happens with hundreds of websites):

[image: AlternativeTo.net]

If one clicks in the box at left from message `Verify you are human` from *CloudFlare*, *Chrome* thinks over and over and after it shows the same page! Sometimes, there are small variations.

There is another site that shows images for the user to select in order to answer a question, but it always gives an error message. It's a infinite loop. This brazilian site also uses *CloudFare*.

However, all sites above works OK in *Firefox* and *Edge* (Microsoft official browser). And the sites also works in *Incognito Mode* inside *Chrome*. However, the brazilian site only works in *Firefox*.

I'm in a desktop with updated *Windows 10* and no antivirus besides *Windows Defender*.

And, yes, I've tried to disable all extensions from *Chrome*, but nothing changes!

I've made a research in the Internet and this problem became common now but there is no presented solution:

[image: Cases]

What's happenning and how to solve it? It's a very serious issue!

**Update**: concerning the comments below, i don't use VPN, neither use active directory.

Concerning the question in the image: `Why I am seeing this page?`

The answer from CloudFlare: `Requests from malicious bots can pose as legitimate traffic. Occasionally, you may see this page while the site ensures that the connection is secure.`

Comment: Try clicking and reading the «Why am I seeing this page» link at the bottom of the verification page.  By any chance, are you using a VPN ? Otherwise, you might be on a public or network that has seen malware activity.

Comment: Are you connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: @TiCPU, no, I'm not using VPN. When rarely I need to use it (country restricted site, for instance), I turn on the Add On and after I turn off.

Comment: @Ramhound, no, I'm not using Active Directory domain. It's a common private computer  with nothing special. And notice that Firefox and until Edge access the site, that Chrome doesn't access!

Comment: The question: Why I am seeing this page?

The answer: Requests from malicious bots can pose as legitimate traffic. Occasionally, you may see this page while the site ensures that the connection is secure.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum - What is your DNS configured to?

Comment: @Ramhound, my option in IP V 4 and IP V 6 is standard (Obtain DNS server address automatically).

Comment: @Ramhound, bingo! I've changed DNS IPv4 in my Ethernet connection and properties.
I've read about and I select  Google Public DNS, item IPv4 (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)  and item IPv6 (2001:4860:4860::8888 and  2001:4860:4860::8844 ) and all sites start to load smoothly.  Amazing!

Comment: Clearly a case of your ISP being the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a specific problem with my ISP provider here in Brazil, that is very known (*Virtua* from *Claro* company).

The solution for me was change the DSN settings.
In my desktop with Windows 10 and network Ethernet card (not WiFi):

**a)** Right click in `System Tray` (bottom right) on network icon
**b)** Click on `Network and Internet Settings`
**c)** Click on `Change adapter options` item
**d)** Rick click on Ethernet connection and select `properties`
**e)** In the list, select `IPv4` and click on `properties`
**f)** In  `Use the following DNS server addresses` section, put a IP address from a public DNS (*see below*)  for `Preferred DNS server` and for `Alternate DNS server`
**g)** Repeat the step `f` for `IPv6` in the list with specific addresses (*see below*). The addresses are always different from `IPv4`IP adresses.

There are many options of free public DNS. The 2 most used options are `Google DNS` and `CloudFlare DNS`.

You can copy and paste 4 times the entire address for `IPv4` and `IPv6`

**Google DNS**
IPv4> *Preferred DNS server*: 8.8.8.8, *Alternate DNS server*: 8.8.4.4
IPv6> *Preferred DNS server*: 2001:4860:4860::8888  *Alternate DNS server*: 2001:4860:4860::8844

**CloudFlare DNS**
IPv4> *Preferred DNS server*: 1.1.1.1, *Alternate DNS server*: 1.0.0.1
IPv6> *Preferred DNS server*: 2606:4700:4700::1111 and *Alternate DNS server*: 2606:4700:4700::1001

Thanks,  [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), for the comments above.